# php multi demension array unsetting

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I'm a bit new and could use a pointer or two..

So the below code displays this:

```
Bill: eats: 0.5, drinks: 0.

John: eats: 0, drinks: 0.

Joe: eats: 0, drinks: 0.
```

See how  bill eats **0.5** ... 
well if bill or anyone else "eats" more than 0
I want them to be removed from the array. I tried to use unset but I'm not sure I'm using it right.

What I expected was John and Joe to be listed like below because bill ate some and got removed..

```
John: eats: 0, drinks: 0.

Joe: eats: 0, drinks: 0.

all done eating.
```

What am I doing wrong, is it the line with **if ($value > 0) unset** ?

```
<?php    

$addresses = array

 (

array("Bill",0.5,0),

array("John",0,0),

array("Joe",0,0)

  );    

echo $addresses[0][0].": eats: ".$addresses[0][1].", drinks: ".$addresses[0][2].".<br>";
echo $addresses[1][0].": eats: ".$addresses[1][1].", drinks: ".$addresses[1][2].".<br>";
echo $addresses[2][0].": eats: ".$addresses[2][1].", drinks: ".$addresses[2][2].".<br>";    

foreach ($addresses as $key => $value)    
{    
    if ($value > 0) unset($key[$value]);      
}  
  if ($var == 0) echo 'all done eating.';

?>
```

Comment: Well, it's not a key/value array. You have an array of arrays.

Comment: You are wrong, every array is a key value array... Only keys are integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate over a twodimensional array.

Thus that means that `$value` is actually a array.

The condition is thus:

```
if($value[1] > 0)//1st element is eats, zero: name, 2: drinks
```

Or a full edit:

```
<?php
$addresses = array (
  array("Bill",0.5,0),
  array("John",0,0),
  array("Joe",0,0)
);

echo $addresses[0][0].": eats: ".$addresses[0][1].", drinks: ".$addresses[0][2].".<br>";
echo $addresses[1][0].": eats: ".$addresses[1][1].", drinks: ".$addresses[1][2].".<br>";
echo $addresses[2][0].": eats: ".$addresses[2][1].", drinks: ".$addresses[2][2].".<br>";

foreach ($addresses as $key => $value) {
    if ($value[1] > 0) {unset($addresses[$key]); echo("removed ".$value[0]."<br>");}
}  
if ($var == 0) echo 'all done eating.';
?>
```

I've added an `echo` statement so one can check the corectness.

Comment: You've got a mistake in your code. Unset should be also changed to unset($addresses[$key]) :).

Comment: Well I've copied it from the question. Thanks. :D

Comment: That works but it doesnt actually remove bill! look at this codepad link where i have it working but not on a multi dimensional.. See when you run it bill is not even showed becuase bill has a value over 0.. http://codepad.org/0d9mj5fa

Comment: In the example you show, you mix up `$value` and `$var` you query for `$value` that is, at that time not defined. Please make sure the problem is specified consistently.

Comment: Next as already specified. You *should not unset `$key[$value]`, but `$array[$key]`*.

Comment: Thanks for your help commuSoft! How can i re -write this line so that it works for all users and not just bill!  if ($value[1] > 0) ...can i do   if ($value[x] > 0)

Comment: The `1` does not refer to "Bill". It simply checks the second **column**, thus the amount of food any person has eaten. If you set the amount of "Joe" to 2, it will still work. http://codepad.org/iN5vStX4 I would advice you to learn something about array variables and semantics first...

Comment: ok now i get it! I have so much to learn!! Thanks for your patience! :) I appreciate it alot.. Have a great day/night..

Answer (score 0):

$value is an array in that case. Try using

```
if ($value[1] > 0) unset($addresses[$key]);
```

BTW, you should try to consider array with string keys. It should be nice and easy to see.
For example:

```
$eaters = array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'John',
        'eats' => 0,
        'drinks' => 0
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'Joseph',
        'eats' => 0.5,
        'drinks' => 0
    )
)
```

And then:

```
echo $eaters[0]['name']; // outputs John.
```

---

**Additional note:**

Unsetting elements in foreach loop **can be sometimes dangerous**. You must be really careful to not unset something that was not looped yet. Another approach is to remember what to delete in another temporary array, and unset in ANOTHER loop.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Quick response :

```
<?php
// ...
foreach ($addresses as $key => $value) {
    if ($value[1] > 0) {
        // you have to unset the entry in $addresses
        unset($addresses[$key]);    
    }
}
// ...
?>
```

:)